# I want to put multiple values from the SQLite database in a listview row

Tags: java, android, listview, row

Android beginner here, I am having trouble populating items in a list view. I can always get one of the database entry values to appear but I would like to have two items per list row. Here is my class for populating the listview. I want to bring the Values for KEY_TITLE and KEY_BODY into a listview. Ideally, I would like KEY_BODY to be a sub item of the listview, but I think that may require a two item listview which I do not know how to implement, even after reading the API's.

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void fillData() {
Cursor moviesCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllMovies();
startManagingCursor(moviesCursor);

String[] from = new String[]{
    MyMoviesDBAdapter.KEY_ROWID,
    MyMoviesDBAdapter.KEY_BODY,
    MyMoviesDBAdapter.KEY_TITLE
};

int[] to = new int[] {
    R.id.text3,
    R.id.text2,
    R.id.text1
};

ListAdapter movies = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.listtextview,
                        moviesCursor, from , to);
moviesCursor.moveToNext();
setListAdapter(movies);
}
```

Here is my XML layout

```
<LinearLayout >
<TextView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/text3"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="15dip"
android:textColor="#a4a4a4"
android:textSize="10sp"
 />
<TextView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/text1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="15dip"
android:textColor="#ffffff"
android:textSize="24sp"
 />
<TextView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/text2"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="15dip"
android:textColor="#a4a4a4"
android:textSize="15sp"
 />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed `BaseColumns._ID`

```
String[] from = new String[]{
    MyMoviesDBAdapter.KEY_ROWID,
    MyMoviesDBAdapter.KEY_BODY,
    MyMoviesDBAdapter.KEY_TITLE,BaseColumns._ID
};
```

Comment: I use KEY_ROWID in place of BaseColumns._ID here is an excerpt from my database adapter                                            `class private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
   "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ("
   + KEY_ROWID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
   + KEY_TITLE + " text not null, "
   + KEY_BODY + " text not null);";`

Comment: ok but u should use BaseColumns._ID that's good and also put colums name in form of string don't need to use     MyMoviesDBAdapter.KEY_ROWID,

Comment: follow my blog for more http://dilipdevelopment.blogspot.in/2012/05/creeate-database-in-android-using.html

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was in my XML layout. I neglected to specify details in the parent "linear layout" which caused my runtime exception. Hope this helps somebody